# Problems after Maven installation - mvn install tries to download unreachable files

Tags: java, maven, deployment, build

After installing maven (`mvn -v` works fine), I tried to do `mvn install` in a directory having a good `pom.xml` at the root of a Maven project that I know works.

I get the output shown at the bottom which basically states that it tried to download a file from an online maven repository and failed.  The file appears to be maven-oriented and I don't think it's related to my project.

In addition, if I run `mvn install` in a directory without a `pom.xml`, which should just fail as I understand it, I get the same problems.  I'm guessing my Maven just hasn't been fully set up yet and its configuring itself maybe?

**Can anyone tell me why it wants these files, and why it might be failing?**

I seem to have access to the URL in chrome and the file being targeted is there, so even if it does need it, I'm baffled about why the download is failing.

```
C:\>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.3.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.3' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: conne
ct
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.3.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.3' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: conne
ct
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

 for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin
```

Comment: Do you have a proxy? Chrome will automatically use your system proxy settings, whereas Maven needs to be [told about it](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html).

Comment: And, yes, Maven will need to download several things the first time it is executed. So that explains why you get the same problem even without a `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Chrome is using a proxy defined by my system, you're right.  I can't even ping the site from my PC but I can visit it in chrome.  I'll check your guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gateway is blocking maven from downloading the dependencies.

Try and check whether you are able to download this pom file manually.

> http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.3/maven-resources-plugin-2.3.pom

if you are open the above URL from your browser, then check your firewall settings(Sometimes firewall settings also block maven from downloading the dependencies, especially if you are in an enterprise environment).

if that is the case, you need to use a proxy to bypass your gateway and download the dependencies

OR

Download the plugins manually from maven central or nexus repository and install it using maven install command in your local .m2 directory.

> maven install -DartifactId="your dependency" -DgroupId="groupID of the
>   dependency"  -DFile="your file location"

As you mentioned in the comments that you are able to open the site from chrome, you can install the dependency using the above command.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to download the artifact from any repository maven:

Check for proxy :if you have some customized jar file related to your company project ,it needs your firewall and if you are using any proxy in setting.xml file then block it to get it downloaded.